# Why HMS Ads Kit in React Native displays package list missing error during build process?

Tags: huawei-mobile-services, huawei-ads

While working with HMS Ads Kit in React Native, project gives package list missing error during build process of the Android folder in the Android Studio. How can resolve the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the new React Native build and update HMS ads sdk, it is recommended to use the minimum targeted api as 19. Also make sure that you import the HMS package to the"MainApplication.java" file even if you are using "AutoLinking".